# store data from conroller to database in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-8

Am getting data from two tables `banks` one has bank details and another has `cheques`. the cheques table has bank_id column where by i loop through and calculate the totals of each bank.

How can i store the data in a table instead of it staying in a variable.

I have a controller to calculate the totals;

```
$banks_data = Bank::all();

   $banks_totals = [];

   foreach ($banks_data as $bank){
       $totals = InsuranceCheque::where('bank_id', $bank->id)->sum('amount');


       array_push($banks_totals,
           [
               'id'=>$bank->id,
               'name'=> $bank->name,
               'description' =>$bank->description,
               'amount'=>$totals,
               'created_at'=>$bank->created_at,

           ]);

   }
```

but how will i be able to access the data in a different controller?

Answer (score 0):

Which table do you want to save it to? Assuming you have a model `BankTotal` that handles the table `bank_totals`, you can do this

```php
   $banks_data = Bank::all();

   $banks_totals = [];

   foreach ($banks_data as $bank){
       $totals = InsuranceCheque::where('bank_id', $bank->id)->sum('amount');


       array_push($banks_totals,
           [
               'id'=>$bank->id,
               'name'=> $bank->name,
               'description' =>$bank->description,
               'amount'=>$totals,
               'created_at'=>$bank->created_at,

           ]);

   }
   BankTotal::insert($bank_totals);//Bulk insert
```

I did not understand the second part of the question on "but how will i be able to access the data in a different controller?"
But you can access the data from another controller by querying the model:

```php
BankTotal::all();
```

Comment: incase i add data to the InsuranceCheque will it update the table for totals automatically?

Comment: No, If you want data to be added automatically, then you need to use the ` created` event on InsuranceCheque model. See this for more info on Laravel invents https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel-model-events-tutorial/